# Distribution of $N$ gaussians after subtracting their mean from each of them

Tags: probability-theory, statistics

Given $N$ iid standard normal random variables $X_1,...,X_N$, we can construct a new random variable by taking their mean $\overline{X}=\frac{X_1+...+X_N}{N}$. We then center the original $N$ variables by subtracting the mean from each of them and end up with a $N-1$ dimensional distribution embedded in $N$ dimensions $$(X_1 - \overline{X}, ..,X_N-\overline{X})$$
I am fairly convinced that this distribtuion is still normal with zero mean. Is there a  nice formula for its density function?

Comment: You need independence or joint normality of $X_i$'s.

Comment: @KaviRamaMurthy This would be sufficient, but not necessary, wouldn't it be? A sufficient (weaker) condition is that $(X_1,\dots,X_N)$ is a normal random vector.

Comment: thanks, I've updated the question!

Comment: Just write down the variance -covariance matrix and use the general formula for  joint normal density.

Comment: @balintm by the way, the characterization of a normal random vector (every linear combination of coordinates is normally distributed) immediately allows you to show that your $(N-1)$-dimensional vector is a normal random vector. Since any linear combination of those $N-1$ things is also a linear combination of the original $N$, and therefore normally distributed.

Comment: @balintm you need to work with multivariate Gaussian vector $x.$ A random vector $x$ is said to be (multivariate) Gaussian if for every (deterministic) vector $a,$ we have $(a \mid x) = a^\intercal x$ is a normal (possibly degenerated, i.e. zero variance) random variable. Your result follows trivially from this.